# Craft CMS solo licence

Tags: license

It mentions developers can use it for personal usage. Does that include **commercial** usage as well? It seems so, but am not sure.

I have a few small personal sideprojects running with some Adsense and Affiliate links (currently on CodeIgniter, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Pixel & Tonic:

> Can I use Craft Solo for client work?
>
> Technically yes, however, we don’t recommend it. Craft Solo is meant to be a solution for developers to get to know Craft and create one-off sites for themselves and their friends. We do not recommend giving admin access to non-developers and therefore strongly recommend that any professional work is done on Craft Pro. This ensures the best experience for everyone.

So as long as you're ok with everyone having admin access (and no branding and no developer support), it's fine, including for commercial usage.

Comment: That's really cool. It'll be a gamechanger.

Comment: FWIW, my rule of thumb has been if I'm being paid to do it, I have my client get a Pro license via their Craft ID. In addition to not wanting non-developers having admin access, I think it only makes sense for them to have support as well.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you may only use it this way if you are a developer and the site is promoting your development services. So in a sense yes it is commercial but I think the use case you describe would fall outside the permitted use.

However, I don't represent P&T, so it may be worth contacting them directly for clarification.

Comment: Please only answer if you *know* the correct answer. Don't guess. P&T explicitly allows commercial use of the Solo license.